# I want to finish an Activity what is not Active

Tags: android-intent

I'm coding Android for 1 week, so sorry for my bad understanding ^^..

For Example i have 4 Activities:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaTw8.jpg

Switching around the A2->A3->A4 and vice versa is done by swiping left or right..

Wenn A1 starts A2, A2->A3, A3->A4, A4->A2  and im now pushing the BACK button i want to come back to A1. BUT if A1->A2, A2->A3, A3->A4 and then BACK i want to come to A3 and so on. if A1->A2, A2->A3, A3->2, A2->A3...A3->A2 and then BACK i want to come to A1..

So what i actually coded is that i start every Activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT for the Intent. Then i called finish(); by A4->A2 and A3->A2 .. the Problem now is that  when the callstack is like this: A1->A2->A3->A4->A2->BACK it will go to Activity A3 and then A1.. but i want directly to A1..

Is there a way to call finish on that A3 when i'm in A4 ? A common way ? Probably storeing the activitys global an and then finishing them in some cases.. but i think that is not the right way..

Hope u can understand my Question^^. And sorry for my bad english

Regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Android.

I think you would like a behaviour like in the Android Play Store App. Swiping left and right. They solved it with Fragments. So you have on Activity with 3 Fragments F2-F4.

Here are some more informations: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

You should use the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for this solution.